# How can I install Oracle Database 18c XE into Windows docker container?

Tags: dockerfile, docker-for-windows, oracle18c

I'm not able to install [Oracle Database 18c Express Edtition](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html) into a Windows docker container.

The Oracle silent setup ([documented here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinw/installing-oracle-database-xe.html#GUID-E6A7B665-134B-4EF3-AB78-A33A54908EB9)) reports success, but no installation is being performed. The destination directory (`C:\OracleXE\`) is empty. And, of course, nothing is installed.

What am I doing wrong here?

#### This is my Dockerfile

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2
USER ContainerAdministrator
COPY / /O18c
WORKDIR /O18c
SHELL ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
RUN New-Item 'C:\db-data' -ItemType Directory; New-LocalUser -Name OracleAdministrator -NoPassword -UserMayNotChangePassword -AccountNeverExpires; Set-LocalUser -Name OracleAdministrator -PasswordNeverExpires:$True; $adm = (Get-LocalGroup | Where-Object {$_.Name.IndexOf('Admin') -eq 0}).Name; Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $adm -Member OracleAdministrator
USER OracleAdministrator
RUN ./Setup.exe /s /v"RSP_FILE=C:\O18c\XEInstall.rsp" /v"/L*v C:\O18c\setup.log" /v"/qn"
EXPOSE 1521 5550 3389
VOLUME C:\db-data
ENTRYPOINT PowerShell
```

#### This is my XEInstall.rsp file

```
#Do not leave any parameter with empty value
#Install Directory location, username can be replaced with current user
INSTALLDIR=C:\OracleXE\
#Database password, All users are set with this password, Remove the value once installation is complete
PASSWORD=foobar123!
#If listener port is set to 0, available port will be allocated starting from 1521 automatically
LISTENER_PORT=0
#If EM express port is set to 0, available port will be used starting from 5550 automatically
EMEXPRESS_PORT=0
#Specify char set of the database
CHAR_SET=AL32UTF8
```

#### This is my directory structure:

[image]

#### This is my docker build command:

```
docker build -f .\Dockerfile  .\OracleXE184_Win64\
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the Oracle setup doesn't work with PowerShell.

When run with standard command prompt, setup installs fine.

#### This is my working Dockerfile

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2
USER ContainerAdministrator
COPY / /O18c
WORKDIR /O18c
RUN PowerShell -Command "New-Item 'C:\db-data' -ItemType Directory; New-LocalUser -Name OracleAdministrator -NoPassword -UserMayNotChangePassword -AccountNeverExpires; Set-LocalUser -Name OracleAdministrator -PasswordNeverExpires:$True; $adm = (Get-LocalGroup | Where-Object {$_.Name.IndexOf('Admin') -eq 0}).Name; Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $adm -Member OracleAdministrator;"
USER OracleAdministrator
RUN setup.exe /s /v"RSP_FILE=C:\O18c\XEInstall.rsp" /v"/L*v C:\O18c\setup.log" /v"/qn"
RUN PowerShell -Command "Get-ChildItem; Get-ChildItem \ -Attributes Directory;"
EXPOSE 1521 5550 3389
VOLUME C:\db-datado
ENTRYPOINT PowerShell
```